# Should this GoT question be reopened now that it has an answer?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to this question: [What happened to Jon Snow? The Evidence, as of ADWD / Season 5](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97665/what-happened-to-jon-snow-the-evidence-as-of-adwd-season-5/)

When it was first posted (Last August), it didn't have an answer, because neither the book nor the show had progressed that far and thus it was closed. But as of this Sunday (with the release of S06E02), this question has a definite answer (which I edited into my answer).

Should this question be reopened now that it as a definite answer? I voted to reopen, but people voted against it:

[image]

Comment: Related discussion  http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/do-we-have-room-for-a-custom-close-reason-for-future-works

Comment: +1, obviously :-)

Comment: The question is asking for the evidence of what happened **as of season 5**, so the fact that season 6 provides an answer is irrelevant with the way the question is worded. If @Randal'Thor wants to update it to take away that particular aspect of the question then I'd be okay with reopening it. (though I'd also downvote because it's just not a great question at that point)

Comment: Open it, as it should be closed as duplicate of: [What is the end of A Dance With Dragons meant to convey about the fate of this character?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/32706/21267)... (One or the other anyway).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I could do that, but as you say, it would then be a trivia question and worth downvoting. I still stick to my belief that it was on-topic even before Season 6 began, because it's not asking what happened to Jon, which would be primarily opinion-based, but **what canon evidence was there** that X, Y, or Z happened to him.